# Selenium Webdriver Log4j warning

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

This is the my code :

```
    public class browserLaunch{
     public static void main(String[]args){
     WebElement usrnTxt=driver.findElement(By.name("txtUserName")); 
     WebElement pswdTxt=driver.findElement(By.name("txtPassword"));
     WebElement lgnBtn=driver.findElement(By.id("btnLogin"));
     WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
     String url=dataTable.getData("General_Data", "Url"); 
     driver.get(url);
     String userName = dataTable.getData("General_Data", "Username"); 
     String password = dataTable.getData("General_Data", "Password"); 
     usrnTxt.sendKeys(userName);
     pswdTxt.sendKeys(password);
     lgnBtn.click(); 
    }}
```

I am getting the below error:

```
        Starting ChromeDriver 2.16.333243 (0bfa1d3575fc1044244f21ddb82bf870944ef961) on port 46496
        Only local connections are allowed.
        log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies).
        log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
        org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element
          (Session info: chrome=47.0.2526.106)
          (Driver info: chromedriver=2.16.333243 (0bfa1d3575fc1044244f21ddb82bf870944ef961),platform=Windows NT 6.0 SP2 x86) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
        Command duration or timeout: 32 milliseconds
        For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
        Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '32a636c', time: '2015-03-05 22:01:35'
        System info: host: 'fa_dev_app_cts2', ip: '10.10.1.33', os.name: 'Windows Server 2008', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.0', java.version: '1.7.0_25'
        *** Element info: {Using=link text, value=Logout}
        Session ID: 5d4102db6a73fccf3ef664877a600625
        Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
        Capabilities [{platform=XP, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, chrome={userDataDir=C:\Users\Sagupta\AppData\Local\Temp\18\scoped_dir22744_17027}, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, version=47.0.2526.106, takesHeapSnapshot=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, browserConnectionEnabled=false, webStorageEnabled=true, nativeEvents=true, hasTouchScreen=false, applicationCacheEnabled=false, takesScreenshot=true}]
            at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
            at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:204)
            at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:156)
            at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:599)
            at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:352)
            at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByLinkText(RemoteWebDriver.java:401)
            at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByLinkText.findElement(By.java:242)
            at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:344)
            at componentgroups.CommonGroups.<init>(CommonGroups.java:13)
            at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
            at supportlibraries.DriverScript.invokeBusinessComponent(DriverScript.java:498)
            at supportlibraries.DriverScript.executeTestcase(DriverScript.java:452)
            at supportlibraries.DriverScript.executeTestIterations(DriverScript.java:406)
            at supportlibraries.DriverScript.driveTestExecution(DriverScript.java:100)
            at allocator.ParallelRunner.invokeTestScript(ParallelRunner.java:58)
            at allocator.ParallelRunner.run(ParallelRunner.java:39)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I am getting the below error as soon as I am starting to execute my TestCase. This error is triggered only when I am initializing the elements with WebElement like:

```
        WebElement usrnTxt = driver.findElement(By.name("txtUserName")).
    Earlier when I initialized my element by 'By' command like: 

        By usrnTxt = By.name("txtUserName") it was working fine.
```

Comment: So what exactly you are looking for :- 1) do you want solution for `log4j` warning or do you want solution for `Selenium WebDriver` `NoSuchElementException`?

Comment: `By usrnTxt = By.name("txtUserName")` is not initializing `WebElement`, you just keep in variable the *how* to look for `WebElement` later.

Comment: can you provide block of selenium code you are trying to execute.